# More eloquent solution for SUMIF of two tables, based on number of countries occurring in cell of table A, divide the corresponding number in table B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, substitution, sumifs

I have two tables (lets say A + B).
Table A includes a number of vehicles to be driven in a set of countries.
Table B includes the planed driven KM per country, from Table A.
(Table A and Table B are on two different Sheets)

On third sheet there is a summary, that should calculate the sum of all planed KM per country.
here is where I'd like to find a "better" solution.

[image]

Currently there are more than one country per week, on occasion. To not clog up Table A or B I have created another sheet with transposed data from table A and B where I have added a column with the formula:

=LEN(Q8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Q8;"-";""))

This counts the number of "-" that occurs and I then use this to divide the planed KM to get the estimate per country.

[image]

In the summary I use:
=SUMIF($V$8:$V$12;"*"&B7&"*";$Y$8:$Y$12) + SUMIF($AA$8:$AA$12;"*"&B7&"*";$AD$8:$AD$12) + SUMIF($Q$8:$Q$12;"*"&B7&"*";$T$8:$T$12)

This can then find a single country when there are more planed in one week. As far I can see this setup works as intended.

Question is, could this be modified to only use the data from Table A + B without the use of my transposed data?

If anyone have any good ideas?

**- Markdown Data**

| Table A | CW12 | CW13 | CW15 | CW16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | SE | DK-DE | DE | AU |
| Car2 | SE | FI | EE | LV |
| Car3 | SE | DK-DE-NL | BE | FR |

| Table B | CW12 | CW13 | CW14 | CW15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | 300 | 150 | 200 | 150 |
| Car2 | 150 | 150 | 150 | 150 |
| Car3 | 200 | 150 | 400 | 300 |

| Summary |  |
| --- | --- |
| Countries | KM |
| SE |  |
| DK |  |
| FI |  |
| DE |  |
| AU |  |
| FR |  |
| NL |  |

**Transposed Data, Car 1**:
=TRANSPOSE(G8:J8), =TRANSPOSE(G13:J13), =LEN(Q8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Q8;"-";"")), =SUM(R8/(S8+1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
=SUM($B$5:$E$7*N(ISNUMBER(FIND(A11,$B$1:$E$3)))/MAP($B$1:$E$3,LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-")))))
```

Result:

[image]

Or to spill result at once with all countries:

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(TOCOL((DROP(REDUCE(0,B1:E3,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,"-")))),1)),3)),MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL((DROP(REDUCE(0,B1:E3,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,"-")))),1)),3)),LAMBDA(z,SUM($B$5:$E$7*N(ISNUMBER(FIND(z,$B$1:$E$3)))/MAP($B$1:$E$3,LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.
I ended up using this formula:

`=HSTACK(MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B7:B13;"-")));LAMBDA(z;SUM($G$13:$J$15*N(ISNUMBER(FIND(z;$G$8:$J$10)))/MAP($G$8:$J$10;LAMBDA(x;COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(x;"-"))))))))`

Since I like the spill, but I want it based on the order I already have them, based per continent and areas.

Comment: Good to hear you were able to adapt it to your needs!

Comment: A followup comment, if I change one of the numbers in Table B to text (and remove the corresponding country from Table A), ex "Transport". Then the whole formula stops working.
Anyway to for the formula to ignore the text and sum the rest?

Comment: Change SUM to SUMPRODUCT and add additional array inside to check if it is a number N(ISNUMBER($G$13:$J$15)) . Try this: =HSTACK(MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B7:B13;"-")));LAMBDA(z;SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER($G$13:$J$15));$G$13:$J$15;N(ISNUMBER(FIND(z;$G$8:$J$10)))/MAP($G$8:$J$10;LAMBDA(x;COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(x;"-"))))))))

Comment: @user11222393 Note that not all the countries would get spilled (check NL). Also SUM and SUMPRODUCT behave the same in Office 365.

Comment: @P.b nice catch with TEXTSPLIT error, ended using REDUCE with enormously long formula! About SUM and SUMPRODUCT I would say same, almost always. Lets say we have A1:A2 {1;2} and B1:B2 {3;"A"}, SUM(A1:A2*N(ISNUMBER(B1:B2))*(B1:B2)) will give #VALUE! error. Even SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2*N(ISNUMBER(B1:B2))*(B1:B2)) will give you very same error unless you use array input instead of multiplying with asterisk inside: SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,N(ISNUMBER(B1:B2)),(B1:B2)) will give no error. To use SUM you would need to wrap inside with IFERROR : SUM(IFERROR(A1:A2*N(ISNUMBER(B1:B2))*(B1:B2),0))

Comment: Check my answer, it's probably more efficient than (as you state) "REDUCE with enormously long formula).

Comment: Definitely it is!

Answer (score 1):

You can bring TableA and TableB into powerquery, and then combine them and generate pretty much anything. Below some potential output versions

[image]

Output Version1

[image]

```
let #"AList" = Table.ToColumns(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(TableA, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Country")),
#"BList" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(TableB, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
NewTable = Table.FromColumns(#"AList" & {List.Last(Table.ToColumns(#"BList"))}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(NewTable, "Countries", each Text.Split([Column3],"-")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Value", each [Column4]/List.Count([Countries])),
#"Expanded Countries" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Countries"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Countries",{"Column1", "Column3", "Column4"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Column2]), "Column2", "Value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Output version2

[image]

```
let #"AList" = Table.ToColumns(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(TableA, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Country")),
#"BList" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(TableB, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
NewTable = Table.FromColumns(#"AList" & {List.Last(Table.ToColumns(#"BList"))}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(NewTable, "Countries", each Text.Split([Column3],"-")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Value", each [Column4]/List.Count([Countries])),
#"Expanded Countries" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Countries"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Countries",{"Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Countries]), "Countries", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Output version3

[image]

```
let #"AList" = Table.ToColumns(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(TableA, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Country")),
#"BList" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(TableB, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
NewTable = Table.FromColumns(#"AList"&{List.Last(Table.ToColumns(#"BList"))}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(NewTable, "Countries", each Text.Split([Column3],"-")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Value", each [Column4]/List.Count([Countries])),
#"Expanded Countries" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Countries"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Countries", {"Countries"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 1):

This lists all the unique countries with their weighted sum based on the number of  counties listed per field in Office 365:

```
=LET(a,TOCOL(B2:E4),
     b,TOCOL(B7:E9),
     c,b/(LEN("-"&a)/3),
     d,UNIQUE(DROP(REDUCE(0,a,LAMBDA(e,f,VSTACK(e,TEXTSPLIT(f,,"-")))),1)),
HSTACK(d,MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(FIND(d,TOROW(a)))),c)))
```

[image]

PS Note that in your example the column headers CW14 and CW16 don't seem to add up. Not sure if that's of influence in a way, if so, please explain further.